# How can i specify the directory in which i want my txt file to be created with python?

Tags: python, directory

I'm currently working on a project on python. In my program i ask the user to input some informations that will be then stored in his document.

```
username = input("Input your username")
w = input("Do you want to view or edit your file?(v/e) ")
    if w == "v":
        open(username + ".txt", "r", "Serax/desktop/Project/Usernames")
    elif w == "e":
        a = open(username + "txt", "a", "Serax/desktop/Project/Usernames")
```

I have manually created a directory in which i want to store all  the users document (name of the directory is "Usernames") it is contained in the "Project" directory.The "project" directory contains the "crypto.py". document and the "Usernames" directory.
I have found out ways to create new directories but i can't find the way to specify the location of my document.
In the complete program i have imported `os`, i. don't know if it could help.

Comment: I don't understand where you're stuck.  You specify the document location just as you would from the command line: give either a relative or absolute path.  Since you just created the directory, you know the path.

Comment: Directories in Python work the same way they do in pretty much every other program.  "Foo.txt" means a file in the current directory.  "bar/foo.txt" means bar is a subdirectory in the current directory, and the file foo.txt within it.  If a file name starts with "/', then it is absolute and starts from the very top.  "/tmp/foo.txt" is the file foo.txt in the global "/tmp" directory.

Comment: @Prune i accidentally pressed post without finishing my question. I didn't know what to write to specify my directory, I tried with a comma after the statement, i didn't know that i should've written the location before the name of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just resolve to the absolute path like `foo/bar.txt` where foo is the child directory in current directory, and use backslashes for windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can append base path to "Usernames" directory as:

```
basePath = "/home/malik/Usernames/"
open(basePath + username + ".txt", "r")
```

Comment: Are you using Windows?